# how to access random task switcher on screen?

Tags: task-management

Sometimes when I (accidentally) swipe the mouse across the screen, all the active desktops show up on the screen at the same time...sort of like Windows Task Manager.

I've tried purposefully swiping the mouse in all directions to make it happen, but no luck so far. What do I need to do to show all active desktops on one screen at the same time?
There must be a setting somewhere...There's one for everything else!

I am using Kubuntu 22.04 (and lovin' it). Thanks for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm loving Kubuntu also - my guess would be that you're activating a Screen Edge / "Hot Corner" feature. If you intentionally put your mouse pointer up to the top-left corner of the screen and leave it there for a second, does that trigger what you're seeing?

If so, you can customize that feature in Plasma's System Settings, under Workspace Behavior > Screen Edges.

Comment: Thanks  J!  Unfortunately, nothing at all happens when I do as you say, except the area immediately under the cursor turns sky blue!

Comment: Hmm - if you into System Settings and then to Workspace Behavior > Screen Edges, do any of the eight boxes on the example monitor there have a black square filled in? (meaning that they already have an edge behavior assigned?)

Comment: J:  top left corner has black square; "present windows all desktops"...That's what I got...now what?   Thanks again!

Comment: Interesting, and yet when you actually move the mouse pointer up to that corner, you don't get the "here are all my open windows" view? (And just checking...do you get that view when you press Ctrl+F10, which looks to be the default shortcut?) And also just checking, are any of the boxes filled in on the equivalent System Settings screen for Touchscreen Gestures, which is right next to Screen Edges?

Comment: J:   Pushing the mouse that way does nothing...BUT...Ctrl + f10 DOES work!!! So that would be the answer....Thank you!